# UIImage (Frame) and UIImage (Picture) merge

Tags: ios, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have multiple sizes of frames, which can be hard coded, or server will decide. I have to select Image from Gallery, which definitely can be of many dimensions.

1. I am selecting Image from Gallery
2. I am generating white background UIImage, using code.

   let size = CGSize(width: 424/2, height: 664/2)

   ```
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
     UIColor.white.setFill()
     UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
     let background_image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
   ```

Now, what I want, to make another Image, which keep Leading 20 pixel, Top 20 Pixel, and width and height 20 pixel smaller than original background.

How can I achieve it.

What I tried before coming to StackOverflow.

```
func mergedImageWith(frontImage:UIImage?, backgroundImage: UIImage?) -> UIImage{

    if (backgroundImage == nil) {
      return frontImage!
    }

    let size = CGSize(width: 424/2, height: 664/2)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let backgroundImage2: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    backgroundImage2?.draw(in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    frontImage?.draw(in: getAspectFillFrame(sizeImageView: size2, sizeImage: (frontImage?.size)!))

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
  }
```

here background image is created with aspect fill, but issue is of starting position and complete height and width.

In very simple words. Its like making custom frames and merge them with images(aspect fill) for printing.

can anyone help me out

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try not ending your image context until all of the images are drawn (I am also including some code that I have working, edited down a bit)

```
class layeredImageView: UIImageView {
var imageBackground:UIImage!
var imageForeground:UIImage!

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    self.image?.draw(in: self.frame)

    imageBackground.draw(in: CGRect(<rect>)
    imageForeground.draw(in: CGRect(<rect>)

    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


}
```

Comment: Problem is in rect, its not fitting as I want, 

Can you see this app.

https://www.lalalab.com/prints

Comment: I have only two images, 

1. Frame, 2. User Image.

Comment: I actually use the above code (that part not included in example) to generate collages (I loop through a set of images and place them in specific parts of the imageView's image). 

The reason I use it in an imageview subclass is I can just use whatever frame the imageView lays out to to do my calculations. So if its 120px on one screen and 150 on another, the other images get to know that info and things draw correctly.

Comment: How can I make it aspect FILL?

    imageForeground.draw(in: frame2)